# Error while installing netbeans 8.2 in Ubuntu 18.04 ￼

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, java, netbeans

Can anyone explain how to install it?

This is the error I get while trying to install netbeans:

[image: netbeans install error]

Comment: Did you have a look into the given installer log file? What does it say there?

Comment: NOrbert -thank u problem solved